# how to send data from js to php and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to send data from js to php and then resend them to the js to use them in a function, this is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "pages/quantity.php",
    data: product,
    success: function(){
    jQuery.extend({
        getValues: function(url) {
            var result = null;

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {
                   result = JSON.stringify(data);
                }
            });

             return result;
          }
       });
    }
});



var q = document.qntfrm.qnt.value;

var max = $.getValues("pages/quantity.php");
alert(max);
```

but I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
    } has no method 'getValues'
```

so where is the error in my code? and is there any better way to do this task?

Comment: Firstly, what is the value of `product`? Secondly, why are you using `$.extend` within the return handler? The error is because you call `getValues` before it's been declared, but I'm not even sure why you're doing this.

Comment: Can you explain this more thoroughly - I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: This function can be greatly simplified

Comment: It *looks* like you're trying to POST data to a .php and then GET data from the .php. Can't the .php simply return the JSON data when you POST to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Moob is right.

Why don't you try something like :

```
var obj = {};
obj.name_of_parameter = val
// val is your param ...
// and name_of_parameter as to match your php get or post variable name

var str = jQuery.param(obj);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'the_url',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: str,
    success: function (data) {
            // code if ok
    },

    error: function() {
        // code if something went wrong
    }
});
```

Comment: this code is working fine, thank you, but I have a question: how I can store `data` parameter to use it outside this function?

Comment: Maybe it's not the best solution. But one would be to create an object in javascript (just before the ajax request), and save the answer into this object :). It will still be available after.

If my answer helped, thank you to up vote it :).